# Unbind listeners in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have function that gets called every time a user scrolls to the bottom, but if he scrolls to the bottom twice the function gets called twice, and I know how to unbind a listener with Jquery but I want to do it with raw JavaScript

Comment: Can you please provide us with the code that calling this function ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `removeEventListener` with the same arguments you passed into `addEventListener` (type and the function). You would need to reference the function using a variable so it can be passed through:

```
var listener = function () {
    ...
};

element.addEventListener("type", listener);

...

element.removeEventListener("type", listener);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `removeEventListener()`:

```
someElement.addEventListener('event_name', boundEventHandler, false);
someElement.removeEventListener('event_name', boundEventHandler, false);
```

In fact, you should always remove all your event handlers in your cleanup, otherwise you'll run into issues like that, with code executing all over the place.

Check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener) for more info.